# Conjugate variable measurement and superluminal signaling

Tags: foundations

In the hard/soft vs white/black experiment from David Alberts book, used in Allan Adams MIT YouTube vid,
the removal of the barrier enables 100 percent measurement of the conjugate variable but "barrier in" gives
random measurement percentages of the conjugate variable.
If the experiment legs were of unlimited length, why does this
not enable superluminal signaling by simply enabling a particular experimental situation without actually  measuring anything.

Comment: Links to YouTube video and abstract page of book?

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2013/resources/lecture-1/